# Swift 2.0+ finding the day of the week a month starts

Tags: ios8, nsdate, swift2, foundation, nscalendar

I am using Swift 2.0+ and need it to be compatible with iOS 8.0+.  I want to find out what day of the week a month starts. For example, November 15 would return Sunday, December 15 would return Tuesday, and January 16 would return Friday.  I think the best approach would be to get the current day of the week and day of the month then count backwards until you reach 1 and get that day.  Currently I have

```
// Returns the day of the week as an integer 1 being Sunday and 7 being Saturday
func dayOfWeek() -> Int {
        let components = calender.component(NSCalendarUnit.Weekday, fromDate: t)
        return components
    }
```

Which calculates the current day of the week, after that I hit a roadblock.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be

```
// This function should return the value I need 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday
    func dayMonthStarted() -> Int {
        // 0 -> Sunday 6 -> Saturday
        var component = calender.component(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: date)
        var day = dayOfWeek()
        while component > 1 {
            component--
            if day == 0 {
                day = 6
            } else {
                day--
            }
        }

        return day - 1
    }
```